# Sum keys of arrays if they match and order it

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with 3 arrays inside.

I have to merge it BUT if a value of any of the three arrays matchs with the value of any of the other two arrays, the keys should be sum.

I.E.
[bing][10] matchs with [google][10] (url not cleaned actually, my mistake) and [yahoo][10]
so the new merged array should have [url][30] in the first position, and so on.

how can I achieve this?

My array: http://pastebin.com/tSfrCcMJ

```
$array = array (
    'bing' => array (
        10 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        9 => 'http://www.stackoverflow.es/',
        8 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions',
        7 => 'http://www.stackoverflow.es/empresa/avisolegal',
        6 => 'http://stackoverflow.net/',
        5 => 'http://chat.stackoverflow.com/',
        4 => 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/',
        3 => 'http://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=all&sort=active&page=16',
        2 => 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com/',
        1 => 'http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ewernli'
    ),
    'google' => array (
        10 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CBYQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFOHjfhg0MrXOGxhxoLkWY6BP7Erw',
        9 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/login',
        8 => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CC0QFjAH&usg=AFQjCNFaLvYDIANOTluG7kTQZppgPK1OuQ',
        7 => 'http://blog.stackexchange.com/&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CDAQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNFM47UgedUUcCIIENkkEpGT1F5-VQ',
        6 => 'http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CDMQFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNEhtBxP6KPK9A2IIHzjqGETn5kVgA',
        5 => 'http://stackoverflow.org/&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CDYQFjAK&usg=AFQjCNFsYAEUQYofh1C2k0IfppDSwwxAUA',
        4 => 'http://stackoverflow.net/&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CDgQFjAL&usg=AFQjCNH55YZyZeh8q75--kYkyCg8nRuf4g',
        3 => 'http://www.crunchbase.com/company/stack-exchange&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CDsQFjAM&usg=AFQjCNETf6XyPdfFqJC5-6F5NFxGjDY2wA',
        2 => 'http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CEAQFjAN&usg=AFQjCNE-vRAAhmbu_OzwpI6EoI-9va12LA',
        1 => 'http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CEMQFjAO&usg=AFQjCNEhsp34I-FC-dW0fG0-ZogG7T-qXg',
        0 => 'http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CEYQFjAP&usg=AFQjCNEf7K09RvPYSDxWKKhDdCpDj1hs1w'
    ),
    'yahoo' => array (
        10 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        9 => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow',
        8 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/about',
        7 => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackoverflow',
        6 => 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/',
        5 => 'http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/',
        4 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions',
        3 => 'http://stackoverflow.net/',
        2 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/faq',
        1 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
    )
);
```

Desired result (I only did the 'http://stackoverflow.com/' match, keys sum):

```
krsort($array);
$result = array ( 30 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 9 => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow', 8 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/about', 7 => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stackoverflow', 6 => 'http://blog.stackoverflow.com/', 5 => 'http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/', 4 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions', 3 => 'http://stackoverflow.net/', 2 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/faq', 1 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 0 => 'http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html&sa=U&ei=oMg7T_rpJ4rz-gazm_SsBw&ved=0CEYQFjAP&usg=AFQjCNEf7K09RvPYSDxWKKhDdCpDj1hs1w', );
```

Comment: can you give that array with `var_export` instead of `var_dump` please? I'm too lazy to convert it.

Comment: So, given that array, what should the result be? Do you actually care what the keys are (if so, why) or do you just want all the unique values?

Comment: @Gordon http://codepad.viper-7.com/GK17Gk - I'll edit the question with it.

Comment: @Gordon learned, thanks. How do you format the array to paste it here?

Comment: @DaveRandom Values should match entirely, check the desired result, but i only did it for 'http://stackoverflow.com/'

Comment: what if two urls have the same score? they'll overwrite each other

Comment: No, it should add in the final merged array. 10 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/', +  10 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/', =  20 => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the score for keys because you risk overwriting values when two entries have the same score. What you can do is:

```
$urls = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function  ($url, $score) use (&$urls) {
    $key = strtok($url, '&');
    $urls[$key] = isset($urls[$key]) ? $urls[$key] + $score :  $score;
});
arsort($urls);
print_r($urls);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [http://stackoverflow.com/] => 30
    [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow] => 17
    [http://stackoverflow.net/] => 13
    [http://stackoverflow.com/questions] => 12
    [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/] => 10
    [http://stackoverflow.com/users/login] => 9
    …
```